# Playing a video in OpenCV

Tags: c++, video, opencv

I am a beginner to OpenCV and I wish to play a video in OpenCV. I've made a code but it's displaying a single image only.
I am using OpenCV 2.1 and Visual Studio 2008.
I would really appreciate it if someone guided me where am I going wrong.
Here is my pasted code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

int main()
{
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("C:/OpenCV2.1/samples/c/tree.avi");
IplImage* img = 0; 
if(!cvGrabFrame(capture)){              // capture a frame 
printf("Could not grab a frame\n\7");
exit(0);}
cvQueryFrame(capture); // this call is necessary to get correct 
                   // capture properties
int frameH    = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
int frameW    = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
int fps       = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
int numFrames = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture,  CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
///numFrames=total number of frames



printf("Number of rows %d\n",frameH);
printf("Number of columns %d\n",frameW,"\n");
printf("frames per second %d\n",fps,"\n");
printf("Number of frames %d\n",numFrames,"\n");

for(int i=0;i<numFrames;i++)
{
IplImage* img = 0;
img=cvRetrieveFrame(capture); 
cvNamedWindow( "img" );
cvShowImage("img", img);

}
cvWaitKey(0);
cvDestroyWindow( "img" );
cvReleaseImage( &img );
cvReleaseCapture(&capture);


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `cvQueryFrame` instead of `cvRetrieveFrame`. Also as pointed out by @Chipmunk, you have to add a delay after `cvShowImage`.

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include "cv.h"       
#include "highgui.h"
cvNamedWindow( "img" );
for(int i=0;i<numFrames;i++)
{
   IplImage* img = cvQueryFrame(capture); 
   cvShowImage("img", img);
   cvWaitKey(10);
}
```

Here is the complete method to play a video using OpenCV:

```
int main()
{
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture("C:/OpenCV2.1/samples/c/tree.avi");

    IplImage* frame = NULL;

    if(!capture)
    {
        printf("Video Not Opened\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int width = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    int height = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    double fps = cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
    int frame_count = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture,  CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);

    printf("Video Size = %d x %d\n",width,height);
    printf("FPS = %f\nTotal Frames = %d\n",fps,frame_count);

    while(1)
    {
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

        if(!frame)
        {
            printf("Capture Finished\n");
            break;
        }

        cvShowImage("video",frame);
        cvWaitKey(10);
    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the cvQueryFrame() and cvWaitKey() functions do seem to have solved the issue.Thank you:)

Comment: one more thing,what's the difference between createFileCapture and captureFromAVI???

Comment: @AaymanKhalid... both are same. You can check at the end of `highgui_c.h` file.

Answer (score 1):

After showing a image on the window, there has to be a delay or a wait before the next image can be show, I think you can guess why that is. Okay so for that delay we use `cvWaitKey()` .
And thats what I have added in the code in the loop.

```
cvNamedWindow( "img" );
for(int i=0;i<numFrames;i++)
{
   IplImage* img = 0;
   img=cvRetrieveFrame(capture); 

   cvShowImage("img", img);
   cvWaitKey(10); 

}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work:( I understand the thing that I am using a loop coz I know the numbre of frames but the purpose of the loop is basically to access the elements index by index. Is there any way to grab frames index by index?@chipmunk

Comment: ` 
IplImage* frame = NULL;
cvNamedWindow("img", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
while (key != 'q')
{   
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    if (!frame)
    {   
        printf("!!! cvQueryFrame failed: no frame\n");
        break;
    }

   cvShowImage("img", frame);

    key = cvWaitKey(27);
}`

Comment: What I have done above is created the window outside the loop and the  IPL image I have declared oustside. This will also increase your performance. And ofcourse its in a while loop now and you dont have to get the frameCount.