# Opencv gives me an unclear camera capture

Tags: c, opencv, netbeans-6.9

I am using Opencv 2.0 in netbeans 6.9 IDE and my OS is windows 7 64bit. When I try to capture a frame from a live feed I get an unclear output.

My laptop cam (Acer crystal eye) is working well otherwise. I tried using a USB camera(logitech) but gave the same result. Below is the simple code I am using.

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv) {    
    CvCapture *video = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
    IplImage * img = cvQueryFrame(video);

if(!cvGrabFrame(video)){
    printf("could not grab a frame\n");
    exit(0);
}

cvNamedWindow("original_image",0);

cvShowImage("original_image",img);

cvWaitKey(0);

cvReleaseImage(&img);

cvReleaseCapture(&video);

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

}

It will be a great help if anyone can help me to sort this out because I am stuck in a project without proceeding. Thanks in advance

Comment: please make this world a better place, and use opencv's c++ api instead

Comment: you mean the problem is that I'm using c language instead of c++

Comment: no, that's not the problem here. still, the old c-api is dead and gone. don't use it for new projects

Comment: berak is quite right unless from some reason you have to use c api ...Otherwise if you are starting new project and don't have ot use c api, use c++ one. And what do you mean by 'unclear output'?

Comment: The video is not being played at all. You are displaying only the first frame. When the first frame is captured, the camera is being initialized and "sees" everything unclear. You have to play video in a loop to get to the next frames. Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15333159/1231073).

Comment: "unclear output" in the sense, it gives the exact picture I am capturing but only highlighting areas that are lighted. other areas are just dark.

Comment: Play arround with your camera settings (contrast, exposure, brightness). What you describe does not seem to be an openCV issue.

Comment: I adjusted them but there were no change at all. Even I tried a logitech camera as well. It gave the same result. That is why I thought that something is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have only shows the first frame of the stream. After opening the video stream, you should make a loop in which you get a new frame from the stream and display it. In your case it would become something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    CvCapture *video = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);

    if(!cvGrabFrame(video)) \\check if the video can be queried for frames
    {
        printf("could not grab a frame\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    cvNamedWindow("original_image",0); \\make your output window

    while(1)
    {
        IplImage * img = cvQueryFrame(video); \\get the next frame from the stream

        cvShowImage("original_image",img); \\show the image in the output window

        if(cvWaitKey(0) == 27) \\if escape key is pressed, exit the loop
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvReleaseCapture(&video);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Erik... This works for me. I tried to take the other frames in a loop as well. But anyhow it didn't work for me. So thank you very much for your help.